# How can I import the user model in Django and select all of the objects

Tags: django, django-views, django-rest-framework, django-users

When I use

```
from django.conf import settings
```

in my DjangoRestFramework views,

```
class UserList(ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

my I receive the error

```
AttributeError at /users/

'str' object has no attribute 'objects'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:9999/users/
Django Version:     1.5.1
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    

'str' object has no attribute 'objects'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` is a string. It is not a model object.

You need to do something like this:

```
try:
    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
except ImportError: # django < 1.5
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
else:
    User = get_user_model()
```

Now,

```
queryset = User.objects.all()
```

-- OR --

if you are using only django 1.5, you can simply do:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

queryset = get_user_model().objects.all()
```